# Relative links in Github Pages without Jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll, github-pages

I created a single-page static website which has been uploaded to GitHub Pages.  I have come across the common problem related to GitHub Pages and relative links.

i.e. "assets/img/img.png" becomes "assets/css/assets/img/img.png"

I found some solutions which involved Jekyll and creating a base url in the _config.yml file.

Is there another solution which does not involve Jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use urls relative to root : `/repoName/assets/img/img.png`.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case :(

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to serve static files on GitHub Pages without Jekyll is to create a file `.nojekyll` in the root of the repository. That will tell GitHub not to parse files as Jekyll.